# How can I make Tor browser use hola VPN

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vpn

The list of Tor exit nodes is known (the NSA, Google, ect...)

There are many more Hola users (48M last I checked), and so many more exit points.

So, ideally, I'd like to point my Tor browser to a Hola exit point, and then browse the internet from there.  Anybody watching the traffic will not know that I am using Tor based on the Hola exit node.

Since Hola works with Firefox (and Tor is a version of firefox) I suspect there should be a way to make this work.

I am aware that, officially, the new versions of Firefox (v40 currently) do not support Hola (the addin seems to be removed from the addin store) but if you click the "settings" item from the Hola taskbar icon, it launches a version of Firefox (3v8) with Hola, that works.

So, how can I do something similar with Tor?

Comment: http://adios-hola.org/ Hola, not even once. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Hola may not be advantageous and instead can even backfire considering the infamous [reports](http://www.businessinsider.in/A-wildly-popular-Google-Chrome-extension-was-being-used-as-a-giant-botnet/articleshow/47462141.cms). In addition, I do think the IP address of those exit nodes are even available, and even if you get one using such 'false' exit node is an overly restrictive/impractical/unstable setup.

You can, though, set preferred entry and exit nodes as well as inform Tor which nodes you do not want to use. For example, you can edit the `torrc` file (which might be in `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/` directory):

```
ExitNodes {us} #use exit nodes in the United States
ExcludeNodes {ru},{ro},{pt},{ph},{pa} #do not use exit nodes from these countries
```